# read .csv after select the file with a button in python

Tags: python, csv

I would like to read a .csv file after the fils with a button but I have an error after selecting the file :

```
file = open(fname, "rb")
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, QStringList found
```

My code is :

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import csv

def import_csv(self):

fname = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, "Open Data File", "", "CSV     data files (*.csv)")

file = open(fname, "rb")
try:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
    print row[1]

finally:
    file.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getOpenFilenames` return a list of filenames, not just one. Perhaps you want to open each file in turn?

Try this:

```
def import_csv(self):
    fnames = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(
        self, "Open Data File", "", "CSV data files (*.csv)")

    for fname in fnames:
        with open(fname) as input_file:
            reader = csv.reader(input_file)
            for row in reader:
                print row[1]
```

Or, if you want to force the user to select only one file:

```
def import_csv(self):
    fname = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
        self, "Open Data File", "", "CSV data files (*.csv)")

    with open(fname) as input_file:
        reader = csv.reader(input_file)
        for row in reader:
            print row[1]
```

Note the distinction between `getOpenFileName` and `getOpenFileNames`.